# replace checkbox with glyph via font-lock

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions, font-lock

I am trying to figure out how how to replace structural elements in org-mode with glyphs/abbreviations to make them more readable. Unfortunately, I'm getting stuck on replacing a simple checkbox `[X]` with `` (glyph).

```
 (font-lock-add-keywords
     'org-mode `(             
                  ("^\s*\\**\\(-\\|\\+\|[0-9]+\\|\\)\s\\(\\[X\\]\\)"
                      (3 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1) 
                                 "")
                            nil)))
                 )
     )
```

My goal is to replace the checkbox capturing group with the glyph, but no matter which group index I pick, I either get a pre-pended glyph or no glyph at all. More disturbingly, this messes with the rest of Org-mode's fontification when you toggle to `fundamental-mode` and then back to `org-mode`. Is this is breaking the syntax table or something? How do you avoid this happening?

### Update

I think the problem is with the complex regex capture groups. I you just code this for the `- [X]` case (no OR expressions needed, one capture group), everything works and the other font-locks do not get messed up.

Comment: Have you located the portion of code in the `org-mode` source that deals with these specific checkboxes; and, if so, can you let us know where it is and what version of `org-mode` your are using?  Some people use the built-in version and others like to pull the latest stable release, and some people are using older versions of Emacs with older built-in `org-mode` versions.  You will almost certainly need to modify the location where this checkbox stuff normally happens, as there is just too much happening in `org-mode` to modify `font-lock` stuff after the fact (in my opinion, that is).

Comment: I use spacemacs, so the version is from the Org ELPA repo: `org-plus-contrib-20170210`. The file `org-element.el` seems to be responsible for defining checkboxes. I wish there was some way to use the built-in faces to do text replacement fontification. Unfortunately, all faces do is colors, fonts etc, but you cannot replace text.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use `font-lock` for this.  Emacs comes with `prettify-symbols-mode` which replaces fixed strings with single character glyphs.  You can add additional symbols to prettify by adding them to `prettify-symbols-alist` a list `(STRING . GLYPH)` pairs

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (push '("[ ]" .  "") prettify-symbols-alist)
            (push '("[X]" . "" ) prettify-symbols-alist)
            (push '("[-]" . "◫" ) prettify-symbols-alist)
            (prettify-symbols-mode)
            ))
```

Of course you can change the glyphs to any that you like.  If you want them to also export prettily to HTML use

```
(setq org-html-checkbox-type 'unicode)
(setq org-html-checkbox-types
 '((unicode (on . "<span class=\"task-done\">&#x2611;</span>")
            (off . "<span class=\"task-todo\">&#x2610;</span>")
            (trans . "<span class=\"task-in-progress\">&#x25eb;</span>"))))
```

There doesn't seem to be a corresponding setting for other export backends.

Comment: Is it possible to specify context with this technique? (a checkbox mid- sentence is not a checkbox)

Comment: `prettify-symbol-mode` only replaces strings; it doesn't understand regexs or anything like that.  I, at least, rarely type "[ ]" except to make checkboxes.  It could happen but maybe not often to enough to offset the awesome looking checkboxes.